# Unable to perform query using jdbc

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I am trying to figure jdbc out for android it seems to not be obtaining any information. I'm not sure is there a problem with the driver or with the connection Strings can someone please tell me I have been trying for weeks.

my logcat gives me the following when I try to run a connection:

```
    02-21 10:55:08.940    9513-9561/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo

02-21 11:23:28.940  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
02-21 11:23:28.940  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method javax.naming.Reference.get, referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.initializeFrom
02-21 11:23:28.940  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14328: Ljavax/naming/Reference;.get (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/naming/RefAddr;
02-21 11:23:28.940  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
02-21 11:23:28.944  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
02-21 11:23:28.948  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo
02-21 11:23:28.948  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1453 (Ljavax/naming/StringRefAddr;) in Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty;
02-21 11:23:28.948  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
02-21 11:23:28.952  19790-19877/net.azurewebsites.cosy D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x37fa at 0x14 in Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty;.storeTo
```

Here is my connection strings

```
    public static final String connectionString = "jdbc:sqlserver://cosy.database.windows.net";
public static final String db_user = "eocribin";
public static final String db_pass = "Ecribin1";
public static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

and here is my helper class:

```
public class BookHelper
{
    private Connection conn;
    private String TAG = BookHelper.class.getSimpleName();


    public BookHelper()
    {
        conn = null;

        try
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"attempt to connect");

            Class.forName(jdbc.DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc.connectionString, jdbc.db_user, jdbc.db_pass);

        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"server broke");

            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"connections fault");

            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }





    public ResultSet getAllDetails()
    {

        Log.d(TAG,"we are connected");
        Log.d(TAG,"starting query");

        String query = "select Bookname, SubjectName from books join Subjects on Subjects.SubjectID = Books.subjectID where classID = '1a'";
        ResultSet temp = null;
        try
        {

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            temp = rs;

        }
        catch(SQLException c)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, c.getMessage());

        }

        return temp;



    }



}
```

when I alter the connection in any way I got a null pointer exception which is weird.

Comment: Note that JDBC is not normally used on Android, as it is not designed for use over WiFi or mobile data connections.

Comment: @CommonsWare would you reccomend using php instead?

Comment: I would recommend a Web service. Whether you implement one in PHP or something else is up to you.